# Why res.redirect is not redirecting the page in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ajax, redirect, handlebars.js, dropdown

res.redirect('/taskswriter') isn't working means not directing to the page I don't know why?

Express.js code:

```
router.route('/update-sources').get(function(req, res) {

  User.updateMany({"Addtasks.commonID":req.query.commonIDs},
     {$set: {"Addtasks.$.status" :req.query.selectedValue }},
    function (error, success) {
          if (error) {
              console.log(error);
          } else {
            User.findOne({tag:"Client","Addtasks.commonID":req.query.commonIDs},
            function (error, data) {
                  if (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                  } else {
                    data.Addtasks.forEach(element => {
                      if(element.commonID == req.query.commonIDs)
                      {
                        var mailOptions2 = {
                          from: 'grumpytext@gmail.com',
                          to: data.email,
                          subject: 'Status changed for the article '+ element.topic,
                          text: 'Writer has changed the status to '+ req.query.selectedValue
                        };

                        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions2, function (error, info) {
                          if (error) {
                            return console.log(error);
                          }
                         else {
                           **res.redirect('/taskswriter');**
                         console.log("Mail sent successfully");
                         console.log("Redirected to taskwriter");
                        }
                      });
}
}); //Mail sent

                    }
            });

            }
    });
  })
```

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/update-sources",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    selectedValue: text,
    commonIDs: id
  },
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(datas){
            console.log(datas);
          alert("Working!!");
      }
});
```

On clicking the one of options in select menu below the above AJAX has been called. Everything is working properly and only the thing is in last the page taskswriter is not getting redirected although i have defined its route as well in the same page.

Hanlebar select menu:

```
<select name="sourcesSelect" id="{{this.commonID}}" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="{{this.status}}">
      <option value="0">In Progress</option>
      <option value="1">Done</option>
      <option value="2">Rejected</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: A redirect in ajax will not redirect the page, you'll have to do that in JS

Comment: How to return response back to the ajax call after successfully called the express route in success callback of AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Update your else part in get route, once the mail send is successful the instead of using `res.redirect('/taskswriter');` use `res.send("SUCCESS");`

Then in your ajax call remove dataType option because if your will give datatype: json then the ajax will expect a json response from the server.

Try this ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/update-sources',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify({
    "selectedValue": text,
    "commonIDs": id
}),
success: (response) => {
    response = response.trim();
    if(response === "SUCCESS"){
        window.location.href = "http:localhost:3000/taskswriter"; //give location where you want to redirect
    }
},
error: (error) => {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(error);
    alert(error.responseText);
}});
```